# Include another script in my parent Perl script

Tags: perl, include

How can I include another Perl script in my base Perl script?

I have a primary source file `test.pl` and I want to include secondary sóurce file `config.pl` within it.

What is a standard method to achieve this in Perl?

Comment: What do you mean by "include"? Do you want to execute the config.pl in the context of test.pl, i.e. should the variables set in config retain their values in test?

Comment: @choroba Yes. But don't want to use system/exec commands.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html

Comment: Using `do` will work, but there are better ways.  Move your config code into a library `Configuration.pm` and then `use Configuration;` in your script is a much saner way of handling code reuse.

Comment: @vinodk89: You have to be mentioned exceptions in your question clearly __don't want to use system/exec commands__

Comment: @xxfelixxx: this works!!

Comment: @xxfelixxx: Did you intend the OP to write a proper module, with `package Configuration` and perhaps `Exporter` functionality? It would probably be better to write this up as an an answer to make these things clear, including the need for a trailing `1;` to prevent the module from mysteriously failing to compile one day.

Comment: [Why is it a bad idea to write configuration data in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5969417)

Comment: @xxfelixxx I wrote those details up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649041/1331451). This should give OP a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the links and suggestions.  I was thinking along the lines of the answer @David Cross gave below, but didn't have time to write it up.

Answer (score 5):

(I'm guessing that the program called `config.pl` sets config values that you want to access in `test.pl`. You don't make that clear in your question.)

A simple example. If `config.pl` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$some_var = 'Some value';
```

Then you can write `test.pl` to look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use feature 'say';

do './config.pl';

say $some_var;
```

But this is a terrible idea for many reasons. Not least because it stops working when you add `use strict` and `use warnings` to either of the files (and you should aim to have `use strict` and `use warnings` in **all** of your Perl code).

So what's a better approach? Turn your configuration into a proper module that returns a hash (I only have a single scalar variable in my example above, but a hash gives you a way to deliver many values in a single variable). A simple approach might look like this.

A module called `MyConfig.pm`:

```
package MyConfig;

use strict;
use warnings;

use parent 'Exporter';

our @EXPORT = qw[config];

sub config {
  my %config = (
    some_var => 'Some value',
  );

  return %config;
}

1;
```

And a `test.pl` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';
use FindBin '$Bin';
use lib $Bin;

use MyConfig;

my %config = config();

say $config{some_var};
```

Having got that working, you can add improvements like parsing the `%config` hash from an external file (perhaps stored in JSON) and then allowing different configurations for different environments (development vs production, for example).

It's a little bit more work than your current approach, but it's far more flexible. And you can use `strict` and `warnings`.